# new Date(...) adds a month forward

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing with node.js, and I'm trying to create a date object on the server.

when coding:

```
var birthyear = 2000;
var birthmonth = 7;
var birthday = 24;
var date = new Date(birthyear, birthmonth, birthday);
console.log(date);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thu Aug 24 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

As you can see, I'm getting August instead of July.

How can I fix that issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The month argument in the `Date()` constructor doesn't start at 1 for January, but instead at 0. Therefore, supplying the month value of 7 gives you the eight month, which is August.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 1):

Months in JS start at `0`
so it's a quite an easy *fix*:

```
var date = new Date(birthyear, birthmonth-1, birthday);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/2T4gA/)**

Answer (score 0):

Months in the JavaScript [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) are 0-indexed, meaning that month `7` actually is August. Use the value `6` for July.

Annoyingly enough, `Date` is rather inconsistent about which fields are 0-indexed and which are 1-indexed, and in fact the same field can be either one depending on the context. You should always refer to documentation when you have to use dates.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, that's weird, but months should be counted starting with

```
0
```